# How to fix the following RegEx?

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I've the following piece of code. I use the Case-insensitve pattern modifier so it will find any occurrence, but what I want is the replacement to be exactly the chars that matched the pattern, keeping the case. How could I fix this?

```
    String str = "Ten tender tEens";
    String substr = "te";
    str = str.replaceAll("(?i)"+substr, "("+substr+")");

    System.out.println( str );
```

*Desired output:*
(Te)n (te)nder (tE)ens

*Received output:*
(te)n (te)nder (te)ens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replaceAll()`  work as the same ways as `matcher(string).replaceAll(exp)`: 
To make this work and for better understanding you can break the code like :

```
     String str = "Ten tender tEens";
     Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile("(?i)(te)");
     Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(str);

     System.out.println(  matcher.replaceAll("$1"));
```

Combining these steps you can  use (does the same):

```
String substr = "te";
str = str.replaceAll("(?i)("+substr+")", "($1)");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?i)("+substr+"?)", "($1)");
```

This will create a group and replace the group.

Comment: I'm quite a newbie to the regex, so I'm not sure what those groups are. But thank you kind sir, you saved me! :)

Comment: @Dane411 this regex is wrong. Why he used `?` mark there? `?` inturn makes the last char in `substr` as optional.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize

Answer (score 1):

You need to use capturing group.

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?i)("+substr+")", "($1)");
```